# Enum method call resolves to to "unused function"

Tags: methods, swift, enums, swift-playground

I've been messing around in Swift with Xcode Playgrounds. I know that Swift enums are much more powerful than their Obj-C equivalents. So I figured I'd make an enum containing colors as the member values, and add a method to the enum to fetch the hex value of a Color.

However, I get an error-- "Expression resolves to an unused function". I have a feeling that it might have something to do with having the method accept a member value as a parameter, but I'm probably wrong. Code's below. Can somebody enlighten me?

```
enum Color {

case Red,Blue,Yellow

func hexValue (aColor: Color) ->  String { //Find hex value of a Color
    switch aColor {
    case .Red:
        return "#FF0000"
    case .Yellow:
        return "#FFFF00"
    case .Blue:
        return "#0000FF"
    default:
        return "???????"
    }
  }
}

Color.hexValue(Color.Red) //Error: "Expression resolves to an unused function"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `static` to the declaration of `hexValue` to create a *type method* that can be called from the type without an instance:

```
enum Color {

    case Red,Blue,Yellow

    static func hexValue (aColor: Color) ->  String { //Find hex value of a Color
        switch aColor {
        case .Red:
            return "#FF0000"
        case .Yellow:
            return "#FFFF00"
        case .Blue:
            return "#0000FF"
        default:
            return "???????"
        }
    }
}

Color.hexValue(Color.Red)  // "#FF0000"
```

Or you could make this nicer by making it a *computed property*:

```
enum Color {

    case Red,Blue,Yellow

    var hexValue: String {
        get {
            switch self {
                case .Red:     return "#FF0000"
                case .Yellow:  return "#FFFF00"
                case .Blue:    return "#0000FF"
            }
        }
    }
}

Color.Red.hexValue    // "#FF0000"
```

Comment: Whoa-- I didn't realize you could use computed properties like that. (I knew you could do Color.hexValue but not Color.Red.hexValue) Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the `hexValue` function as static, because you're not calling it from an instance.

Note that the `default` case is unnecessary, because all possible values are already handled in your switch statement.

However, swift enums are more powerful than that. This is how I would implement it, taking advantage of raw values:

```
enum Color : String {

    case Red = "#FF0000"
    case Blue = "#FFFF00"
    case Yellow = "#0000FF"

    static func hexValue(aColor: Color) -> String {
        return aColor.toRaw()
    }
}
```

and obtain the string representation using:

```
Color.hexValue(Color.Red)
```

The `hexValue` method is redundant though, because you can just use:

```
Color.Red.toRaw()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read the error message!

```
    let color = Color.hexValue(Color.Red)
```

you have to assign the return value to something

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `Printable` protocol and implement a `description` computed property on your Enum, then you can just reference its value using string interpolation.

```
enum Color: Printable {
    case Red,Blue,Yellow

    var description: String {
        get {
            switch self {
                case .Red:     return "#FF0000"
                case .Yellow:  return "#FFFF00"
                case .Blue:    return "#0000FF"
            }
        }
    }
}

let myColor = "\(Color.Red)"
```